# can not convert value type "string?" to expected argument type "inout string"

Tags: swift, string, swift2, swift3

this line `self.displayResultLable.text +=  (title as! String)` error throwing

> can not convert value type "string?" to expected argument type "inout string"

Here is my code :

```
   if results.count > 0 {
                    var displayResult : String?
                    for books in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                        if let title = books.valueForKey("title") {

                            self.displayResultLable.text +=  (title as! String)

                        }
                    }
                }
```

what is the `inout` string here ? what is the best practice ?

Note this line  `self.displayResultLable.text =  (title as! String)` working fine:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to write it like this instead:

```
self.displayResultLable.text =  self.displayResultLable.text! + title as! String
```

It´s because of the left side is an optional and the right side is not and they don´t match. That´s why you need to write label.text = label.text +...

I can also suggest you to change your `if let` to this instead:

```
if let title = books.valueForKey("title") as? String {
   self.displayResultLable.text = (self.displayResultLable.text ?? "") + title
}
```

Comment: displayResultLable.text is option  type ?

Comment: @twilight2, it´s because of the left side is an optional and the right side is not and they don´t match. That´s why you need to write `label.text = label.text +...`

Comment: What if `self.displayResultLable.text` has not yet been assigned a value (i.e., has value `nil`)? Then the explicit unwrapping of it in `... = self.displayResultLable.text! ...` will yield a runtime exception. Using the explicit ("forced") unwrapping **should never be encouraged**, not unless it has been asserted that the object for unwrapping is non-`nil`. A more safe approach would be to e.g. use the `nil` coalescing operator to set a defailt "current state" of the text in case its `String` property is `nil`. E.g. `self.displayResultLable.text = (self.displayResultLable.text ?? "") + title`

Comment: Also, note that there exist no overload of the `+=` for optionals (i.e., no `+=` operator even if both lhs and rhs are optionals of the same wrapped type). The reason is quite apparent; given two optionals (of same wrapped type), say `lhs` and `rhs`, if either `lhs` or `rhs` is `nil`, what would be the resulting value of `lhs` for `lhs += rhs`?

Comment: @dfri your comment really useful . thank you so much

Comment: @twilight2 happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the optional chaining operator to only perform the addition of text if the optional (`self.displayResultLable.text`) is non-nil:

```
self.displayResultLable.text? +=  (title as! String)
```